# jScrollPane - Scroll bar doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Please take a look at:
http://www.valatka.com/work/jscrollpane/

The block of text just below the "Fine Print" heading should have a scroll bar to the right, but it's not there.

I think I've got the same jScrollPane (v2) js and css files that Kevin used in this basic example page:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

This example page works in my browser(s).  The one I'm trying to get to work doesn't work anywhere.

Any help or insight you can provide will certainly be appreciated.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of js file your version is 2011-07-04
but the current one and is working is 2012-09-27

Project: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

GitHub: http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane

Source: http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js

Minified: http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js

try the last version and tell me, if still the problem there
My Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call

```
$("#somediv").jScrollPane()
```

**after** div content was loaded (for example if using AJAX). In other case content height will be equivalent to 0 and controls won't shown.

Also remember to reinitiate jScrollPane every time you've changed content.

Answer (score -2):

The `<div class="jspVerticalBar"></div>` markup is missing in your page.

Also, in the demo the paragraph text is inside `<div class="jspPane"></div>` while your text is outside it.

Update your markup structure to match the demo and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I figured how to make the scrollbar finally appear.  As you probably have noticed from my HTML, I used a `<div>` to enclose text (without `<p>` around the text).  To this `<div>` I applied the id to have the jScrollPanel act on it, and that didn't work. Previously, I had used `<p>` with the id instead of `<div>`, as I saw it in some sample code, to enclose the text.  It turns out I needed to enclose the text in a `<p>`, and enclose that paragraph with a `<div>` with the id of "fine_print".  This was how it was done in Kelvin's demo and I missed it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because the referenced elements (i.e. those with classes `jspVerticalBar` and `jspPane`) are what the script generates. They're not to be present in the HTML source.